# Plotting data on Python from an ASCII file

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I have an ASCII file (that can be opened as a txt file). I have data (result of a numerical simulation) in a way that 41 data are written (separated by a space), then there is new line where the next 41 data are written and so on.

I want to extract the file and plot in the x-axis numbers starting from a value (that I extract from a variable value in another python file) incrementing with a constant value, and in the y-axis, the data of the LAST LINE of the ascii file in order.

I tried but I get an empty graph for some reason

Comment: Show us your code and maybe someone will be able to highlight your shortcomings

Answer (score 0):

1. the *x*-values

   ```
    # read your data from your files,
    # here I read them from the terminal.
    # Remember that what you read is always a string,
    # and you have to convert to the appropriate type
    # (here you must convert to `float`)

    x0 = float(input('X start at:  '))
    dx = float(input('X increment: '))
    npts = 41
    x = np.linspace(x0, x0+dx*npts-dx, npts)
   ```
2. read the data, a file object has the `.readlines()` method that returns a `list` of strings, one for each line, so we address this list with `[-1]` to get the last line, finally we split the last line in a list of strings that eventually we convert to `float`s

   ```
    last_line = open(
    #    123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+1
        'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.txt'
    ).readlines()[-1]
    y = [float(n) for n in last_line.split()]
   ```
3. plot, no comments

   ```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
   ```